# Can I set this column as the primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, primary-key

I'm new to SQL Server and would really appreciate it if you could help me out here.

So are a healthcare provider and internally we assign an ID to each patient (for example, `1234`). I'm currently constructing another database, and I just wonder can I use our internal IDs as primary key, given they are unique? If so, since I am not going to do any calculation on the primary key, can I set them to string/char datatype for primary key?

Comment: If the `ID` is always numeric then go with `Integer` type. Integer type doesn't mean you have to perform some calculation on them. Integers can be helpful when you are querying or ordering your results than `Varchar`

Comment: `INT` data type defined as identity is more common and faster than other types.

Comment: Be careful with using something as a primary key when there is the slightest chance that it might mean something more than just a key to you. If ever a key needs to be changed because the "internal ID" happens to change, or for some other reason the key is dependent on external factors, it is better to define it as a normal field, and use a database generated key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, yes you can but it is **not recommended at all!**

To give you some heads up:

- Primary keys should never change
- You cannot use a natural key or a key form other system
- They cannot have any formula
- Use short but suitable key type

If you have an external key that you want to use to find some patients, create another column for it and add [UNIQUE Constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) to it.
just don't forget to add index for that column

Read this post of mine for more information:

http://pilpag.blogspot.dk/2016/06/relational-database-designsimple-rules.html

Answer (score 1):

The conditions for a primary key are that the key is unique in the table and never `NULL`.

Your patient id would appear to have these characteristics.

That said, there are good reasons for developing a synthetic primary key (auto-incremented/identity/serial depending on the database).  More importantly, the actual patient ID may be sensitive information.  For instance, patients might use the id when logging in or it might be printed on invoices.

It might not be a good idea to have sensitive information repeated throughout the database.  For this reason, an "internal" id would be used to refer to patients in table and all the sensitive information would be contained in one or a handful of tables.

This would perhaps be more obvious if the "patient id" were a government id ("social security number") or email address.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the ID can also be numeric and a primary key - it doesn't have to be a string.  As long as the ID is unique, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use your internal IDs if they are unique;PK limit is 900 bytes for char/varchar data types.So if your IDs are int is fine. But if your IDs can change with time or can be reused them for more than one patient I strong recommend not to use them to avoid chaos. I prefer a surrogate key, like an identity

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are assigning each patient a number so as to uniquely identify them. So a report would contain the patient number rather than only a patient's name which can be ambiguous. You won't ever change the patient numbers, because then you'd have to change this in all databases and would have to re-print all documents on the patient that are still needed. This makes this number a perfect primary key for a patient table in any of your databases.

You *could* use a generated technical ID instead as the table's primary key and have the patient number only as another field in the table (which would still have a unique constraint of course, because it is still the business key uniquely identifying a patient). Whether to do this or not is mainly a matter of personal preference and experience. I prefer natural keys over IDs (so *I* would make the patient number the primary key). This stems from having worked with rather large databases with thousands of tables and much hierarchy where the natural keys proved to result in faster queries, enhanced data consistency and easier maintenance. Others may have different experience, though.

**So yes, the patient number seems to be the perfect natural primary key in my opinion.**